# Bootstrap 3 Grid switching rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid

I need some help for getting the html right for a grid I'm trying to create. There should be two views: one for desktop and one for mobile. The desktop should look like this:

```
|1|2|3|4|5|6|
|a|b|c|d|e|f|
```

When resizing the screen to a small size, the grid should look like this:

```
|1|2|3|4|
|5|6|a|b|
|c|d|e|f|
```

Does anyone knows if this is possible by just bootstrap? My desktop version is correct but when the screen gets smaller the grid resizes to this:

```
|1|2|3|4|
|5|6|
|a|b|c|d|
|e|f|
```

You can view the JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D3UAe/).

Comment: Combine your classes, you can combine the `col-lg` options with the `col-sm` ones. Thats what makes bootstrap easy! Classes to rule them all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're putting everything in the same row, it should work.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> 1 </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> 2 </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> 3 </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> 4 </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> 5 </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> 6 </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> a </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> b </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> c </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> d </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> e </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> f </div>
</div>
</div>
```